# Como fazer um loop no jquery assim que carregar a pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery

salve pessoal!
Eu tenho um desenho de uma seta, e gostaria que ela se move-se para baixo e para cima sem parar, a partir do momento que alguém carregasse a pagina.

```
$(document).each(function() {

  $('#seta').animate({top: "100px"}, 1000 ),
  $('#seta').animate({top : "-100px" }, 1000);

});
```

eu fiz assim e parece que funciona, mas ele so desce e sobe e ai para de vez.
eu li um pouco a documentação do jquery ate chegar nesse `.each()` mas estou com problemas para entender por que não esta funcionando, agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O `each()` você usa quando quer percorrer uma coleção de elementos com um
>   mesmo identificador (uma classe, tag, atributo etc.). Não se aplica ao seu caso.

Pode criar uma função que irá receber um parâmetro (*true* para cima, *false* para baixo) para saber se o elemento irá ir pra cima ou para baixo, e o *callback* da animação irá chamar a função novamente alternando, criando um *looping* infinito:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   (function mover(i){
      
      $('#seta').animate({top: (i ? "-" : "+")+"100px"}, 1000, function(){
         mover(!i);
      });
      
   }())
   
});
```

```css
#seta{
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="seta">
   seta
</div>
```